# Recommended order of completion?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

I will be doing all of these in the end. Should I do, all by Rudin, in the order:

> 1)Principles of Mathematical Analysis
>
> 2)Real and complex Analysis
>
> 3) Functional Analysis

or

> 1) Principles of Mathematical Analysis
>
> 2) Functional Analysis
>
> 3) Real and Complex Analysis

I can't find any information about which order is best. Thank you

---

Which would be optimal in terms of preparing me for the next content so I can appreciate it better?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the following order is more natural

```
1)Principles of Mathematical Analysis

2)Real and complex Analysis

3)Functional Analysis
```

but there is no requirement to just use the books Rudin. You can mix with books from other authors too...

Comment: Why is it more natural?

Comment: @PMARCAFAorPMAFARCA Because functional analysis usually comes after real and complex...

Comment: @PMARCAFAorPMAFARCA functional analysis uses concepts discussed in real analysis

Comment: Strange. I am taking functional before real&complex at my university

Comment: Metric spaces: elements of topo; compactnes; completenes; contraction mapping principles; theorems on continu & compactnes. Normed, Banach & Hilbert space: strong & weak convergence; orthogonal system; orthogonal complement; projection theorems, linear functionals, Riesz representation theorems. General topological space.

Comment: Is that difficult without real&complex?

Comment: Am I doomed?${}$

Comment: ? You tell us! Didn't you say you were taking functional right now? Or are you *about* to start?

Comment: @PMARCAFAorPMAFARCA you will need an understanding of integration, measure theory, sequences, convergence,...

Comment: @induktio About to!!!

Comment: @sanjab I know integration, I don't know what measure theory is, sequences and convergence are pretty easy from calculus

Comment: @PMARCAFAorPMAFARCA you will need to know the lebesgue integral (that is usually introduced in measure theory). you need to know what vector spaces are. it is not impossible to take functional analysis first. IIRC the lebesgue measure is introduced in rudins real and complex analysis

Comment: I can't understand how can you understand functional analysis without taking real and complex analysis.

Comment: @Hamza That isn't good... Now I am a little worried

Comment: @sanjab I have a lot of prereading to do!

Comment: @PMARCAFAorPMAFARCA I want to know witch examples of Banach spaces you know, may you give me some examples ?

Comment: lol I'd drop that class faster than the feds dropped Bonny and Clyde

Comment: @Hamza I don't know what a banach space is

Comment: @induktio Can't drop, already paid for and required for progression now that they are locked in!

Comment: @PMARCAFAorPMAFARCA Unfortunately, [this](http://i.imgur.com/mHM3DMk.gif) was my reaction when you said you couldn't drop.

Comment: @induktio Well that isn't nice lol

Comment: @induktio I'll get a High Distinction for you  then :P

Comment: That would be nice. I'd like that. I'd talk to someone in the administration about your situation though--not a good idea to take that class *at all*.

Comment: @induktio Surely they will teach me banach spaces and stuff

Comment: @PMARCAFAorPMAFARCA lol

Comment: @induktio How could they start talking about banach spaces without defining them atleast, that wouldn't make sense. You really think they won't teach me the stuff?

Comment: @PMARCAFAorPMAFARCA which university is it? ask the prof. about it?